# Is it exists any "rss hosting" with API for creating feeds

Tags: language-agnostic, rss, atom-feed

I am creating a desktop app that will create some reports. I want to export these reports as RSS or ATOM feeds. I can easily create feeds with Rome lib for Java. But I have no idea how to spread them. I thought about embedding httpd into my app, but it's bad idea, because a computer can be behind NAT or turned off.

I need some kind of "proxy" server, where can I push my feeds, and clients will be able to pull content from that server.

I can probable write server side app fore this, but first I'd like to find out if  some dedicated solution is available for problems like this.

I was also thinking about using some blogging platform and using its API. What do you think about this approach?

One more thing I have to consider when choosing platform ability to handle lot of updates. Sometimes desktop app will be shut down but when it will be running, it generates quite a lot of updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Google's [feedburner](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?answer=79408).

**EDIT**

Here's a better link for their [help / faq](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/).  You'll still need to use some service to generate your feed, but it won't have to handle a heavy load.  Feedburner will poll your feed every 30 minutes and their servers will act as a proxy for your feed.  As far as how to publish the feed for Feedburner to read, I would recommend writing a service to handle this, even more considering that you getting the data for the feeds from a number of desktop applications, and it'll probably be easier to write a custom service to interface with them, store your data in a DB, and publish feeds than it would be to try and modify a blogging service for this purpose.

Comment: I checked feedburner earlie, but I cant found any push option. I think I must have server with my feed and feed burner it's only proxy with adds and analytic options. Am I wrong?

Comment: If I was going to go about this I would want to create my own service for the desktop clients to post to, and to create feeds for feedburner or a similar service.  Basically what you are trying to do is alot like what Twitter.  You create an service for multiple clients to make frequent updates to, then publish RSS feeds of the updates.  Is that about right?  It is similar to a blogging platform as well, and you could probably modify one to do what you want, but if it were me I'd rather write a service to fit the bill than try to modify another to a different purpose.

Comment: Oh...I should have started that comment with "yes, you are right".  You still have to create some service to handle the posts from the clients and publish an RSS feed to feedburner.  Feedburner is not a service you can push your feeds to, but it is a proxy that can reduce your own server load and add some analytics.

Comment: Ok, thank You for explain. I will think about it, maybe it's not bad idea using my own service.

And yes, it is a little bit like Twitter, but "inverted". I will have a lot of updates, and only few viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I didn't think of this when I first answered your question, but Yahoo has a service called [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) which allows you could use to generate feeds from various kinds of inputs.  I'm not sure how well it would scale but it might work for you.

Comment: I also taught about yahoo pipes, but I think I' cant push anything to it. To use it I would need pushing text or xml files on my own hosting (using my own app with my own api, or ftp). So I don't think it's much better then feedburner. Ok, It's much more flexible, but still it doesn't solves all problems.

But thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: I don't know what your service requirements are, but you could always piggy back on some existing push service, say twitter for example, then use yahoo pipes to stitch things together.  Of course the easier way is to again make your own service I suppose.  I using pipes today to integrate some feeds into an automatic ticketing system and was reminded of this question.